# Is HashSet faster than Set in Dart?

Tags: dart, hashset

Some people uses `HashSet` instead of `Set` and I don't know the why, is it faster? The [description](https://api.dart.dev/be/175791/dart-collection/HashSet-class.html) in Dart is unclear for me and I have not found examples about their differences or reasons when to use one or the other.

Comment: I don't know anything about Dart, but I can tell you that in general, many programmers have been misled into believing that HashSets are "faster" because the textbook says a hash lookup is O(1) and that is better than a red-black tree commonly used by Set implementations.  In practice the tree is often faster.

Comment: Well [Set](https://api.dart.dev/be/175791/dart-core/Set-class.html), is an abstract class that [HashSet](https://api.dart.dev/be/175791/dart-collection/HashSet-class.html) implements. The default implementation is a [LinkedHashSet](https://api.dart.dev/be/175791/dart-collection/LinkedHashSet-class.html). The standard library also includes a [SplayTreeSet](https://api.dart.dev/be/175791/dart-collection/SplayTreeSet-class.html). The main difference between HashSet and LinkedHashSet is that LinkedHashSet keeps track of the order that key/value pairs were inserted and HashSet does not.

Comment: From first principles, HashSet will be marginally faster (and use less memory) than LinkedHashSet (the default implementation for Set) because it doesn't need to maintain the links that the latter uses to order the entries.  So if the order of the set elements is irrelevant, HashSet is a better choice.

Comment: I know it's not allowed here, but unfortunately chatGPT gives a detailed explanation of the difference between them and why HashSet is a bit faster

Comment: @mmcdon20 Why did you write that answer as a comment?

Comment: Generally speaking, instead of asking us, why *some people* do something, why don't you ask *some people* directly? They are way better at explaning their thoughts, than we are at guessing what those thoughts were.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, `LinkedHashSet` (Dart's default `Set` implementation) requires more memory and time than `HashSet` due to the storage and maintenance of links for ordered operations.

`HashSet` from `dart:collection`, however, does not have a `const` constructor. `LinkedHashSet` may be better for immutable sets consisting of `const` values for this reason - it depends on the specific requirements of the project.